# sftp prompt hangs on ls with chroot users authenticated with pam_mysql

Tags: ubuntu, sftp, pam

OS: ubuntu 14.04

I setup pam_mysql, and it's working. I can login sql users via regular ssh/sftp just fine. The problem comes when I try and sftp using CHROOT sql users. Anytime ls is entered it hangs.

- sshd log: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7e4728909608a4177abd3de46178bbca
- auth.log: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1e161ab51981629e6061ba315d936571
- sshd config: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0cf6cfceddcd6f53631dd1c8bed84b56
- nsswitch: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7ace0709cf2011c4fa2abeb20a4d6e43

Stops at:

```
root@default-ubuntu-1404:~# sftp test@localhost
Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
test@localhost's password:
Connected to localhost.
sftp> ls
... just hangs
```

Other commands work, (cd, pwd)

This seems to be a similiar issue: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32882/sftp-server-on-rhel6-disconnects-on-ls

"This ended up being an issue with Likewise Open. "ls" was the only command that try to resolve UID/GID when sftp'ing, and in doing so, it went to likewise for resolution, and as soon as it did, it crashed."

I can't wrap my head around it, but once the user is inside of the chroot env it can't get uid/gid info is my guess.

Comment: Make sure the directory in question doesn't have a massive number of files in it. This is known to cause that problem.

Comment: No that's not it there are only a test directory and file I created. Thanks for the response though.

Answer (score 0):

So it's not "solved" the way I want it to be, but I figured out a work around.

Creating a `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` files inside of the chroot folder of the user solves the problem.

Not a great work around but it works, I need to populate the `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` file with the values from `getent passwd` for the pam_mysql users.

Im working to make a script to create these with pam_exec on user login.

root and the user's uid/gid should be all that's needed in each user's chroot.